# Как исправить ошибку PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

```
<form action="pay.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" value="https://vk.com/feed">
    <input type="radio" value="https://twitch.tv">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['value'])) {$value = $_POST['value'];}
header('Location: ' . $value);
?>
```

Comment: Во-первых, просто перенесите php код вверх страницы и всё заработает, во-вторых, тревога -> дубликат.

Answer (score 0):

Помните, что функцию header() можно вызывать только если клиенту еще не передавались данные. То есть она должна идти первой в выводе, перед ее вызовом не должно быть никаких HTML-тегов, пустых строк и т.п.

Comment: Можно буфер также очистить предварительно

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте очистить их предварительно:

```php
if (!headers_sent()) {
  foreach (headers_list() as $header)
    header_remove($header);
}
```